# How do I calculate the ADI and COV of time series data using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-series, classification

I'm trying to classify time series data using SQL. I have data for a reference data point that occurs over 3 years. So the reference occurs 36 times, one for each month. Sometimes the quantity is 0, other times it may be 25 or even higher for each row. What I want to know is how to calculate these equations using SQL (MSSQL in particular).

[image]

[image]

Then, similarly, I want to classify the data into `Erratic`, `Smooth`, `Lumpy`, and/or `Intermittent` [as seen here](https://frepple.com/blog/demand-classification/).

> Smooth demand (ADI < 1.32 and CV² < 0.49). The demand is very regular
> in time and in quantity. It is therefore easy to forecast and you
> won’t have trouble reaching a low forecasting error level.
>
> Intermittent demand (ADI >= 1.32 and CV² < 0.49). The demand history
> shows very little variation in demand quantity but a high variation in
> the interval between two demands. Though specific forecasting methods
> tackle intermittent demands, the forecast error margin is considerably
> higher.
>
> Erratic demand (ADI < 1.32 and CV² >= 0.49). The demand has
> regular occurrences in time with high quantity variations. Your
> forecast accuracy remains shaky.
>
> Lumpy demand (ADI >= 1.32 and CV² >=
> 0.49). The demand is characterized by a large variation in quantity and in time. It is actually impossible to produce a reliable forecast,
> no matter which forecasting tools you use. This particular type of
> demand pattern is unforecastable.

Here is the query that produces the table that I am working with.

```
SELECT
distinct
CHAN_ID
,PROD_CD
,CP_REF
,PARENT
,ORDERED_DATE
,QUANTITY
FROM DF_ALL_DEMAND_BY_ROW_V
where parent is not null
```

`CP_REF` is the ID that I am focusing on.

Here is an example of the top 12 rows.

[image: Sample data]

Please ask if you need more clarity. My SQL skills are barely basic.

Comment: Why are you using `select distinct`? Where are the data columns?

Comment: Not sure I understand. The equations for `ADI` and `COV` are what I'm trying to calculate. So `QUANTITY`, `ORDERED_DATE`, and `CP_REF` are the ones in particular that I am most concerned with.

Comment: So how are the reference points connected? They have the same `CP_REF`?

Comment: What do you do when the denominator is zero?

Comment: Good question. We will have to catch that error and classify that data as smooth. And, yes, the `CP_REF` is the unique identifier for the data that I want to classify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select
        CP_REF,
        count(*) * 1.0 /
          nullif(count(case when QUANTITY > 0 then 1 end), 0) as ADI,
          stdevp(QUANTITY) / nullif(avg(QUANTITY), 0) as COV
    from DF_ALL_DEMAND_BY_ROW_V
    where parent is not null
    group by CP_REF
)
select
    CP_REF, ADI, COV,
    case
        when ADI <  1.32 and COV <  0.49 then 'Smooth'
        when ADI >= 1.32 and COV <  0.49 then 'Intermittent'
        when ADI <  1.32 and COV >= 0.49 then 'Erratic'
        when ADI >= 1.32 and COV >= 0.49 then 'Lumpy'
        else 'Smooth'
    end as DEMAND
from data;
```

Double check that you want to use `stdevp()` and not `stdev`. I wish I were more knowledgeable about statistics.

Comment: How do I now take this and join it with another table?

Comment: I guess that depends on what you want to accomplish and what the relationship is.

Answer (score 0):

As per the link, COV should only include the non-zero periods. And we'll need to square it before comparing. So the corrected COV should be computed as: `pow(stddev(nullif(QUANTITY, 0)) / avg(nullif(QUANTITY, 0)), 2) as COV`